# draw a straight line with a starting touch point

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cgrect, touchesbegan, uigraphicscontext

I want my swift code to draw a straight horiziontal line. Right now it selects a point and the user extends the line anchored in the first point. I just want the user to be able to draw the line left or right. I tried alternating        bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:startTouch!.x, y:startTouch!.y)) but that does not seem to have any effect.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView!

    var startTouch : CGPoint?
    var secondTouch : CGPoint?
    var currentContext : CGContext?
    var prevImage : UIImage?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        drawingPlace.backgroundColor = .gray
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        startTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches{
            secondTouch = touch.location(in: drawingPlace)

            if(self.currentContext == nil){
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingPlace.frame.size)
                self.currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            }else{
                self.currentContext?.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawingPlace.frame.width, height: drawingPlace.frame.height))
            }

            self.prevImage?.draw(in: self.drawingPlace.bounds)

            let bezier = UIBezierPath()

            bezier.move(to: startTouch!)
            bezier.addLine(to: secondTouch!)
            
            bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:startTouch!.x, y:startTouch!.y))
            bezier.close()

            UIColor.blue.set()

            self.currentContext?.setLineWidth(4)
            self.currentContext?.addPath(bezier.cgPath)
            self.currentContext?.strokePath()
            let img2 = self.currentContext?.makeImage()
            drawingPlace.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: img2!)

        }
    }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        self.currentContext = nil
        self.prevImage = self.drawingPlace.image
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw a horizontal line, create a `CGPoint` whose `x` is the location of the touch and whose `y` is that of the starting point. That will result in a horizontal line.

---

That having been said, here are a few other of observations:

1. If you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, you must call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`. You should do this within `touchesMoved`, not trying to hang on to the context beyond this call.
2. If you were to do this, we would generally use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` nowadays.
3. Personally, I wouldn't try rendering an image for every touch. That is a pretty expensive operation. I would just add a `CAShapeLayer` and then update the `path` for that layer. Let `CAShapeLayer` take care of the rendering of the path.
4. I'm not quite sure why you are iterating through the array of touches. I would just grab one and use that.
5. I might suggest using predictive touches to minimize perceived lagginess.
6. The `startTouch` is actually a `CGPoint`, not a `UITouch`, so I might call it `startPoint` instead.
7. If you want to make a snapshot image, I'd do that in `touchesEnded`, not in `touchesMoved`.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    var startPoint: CGPoint?

    let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        imageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        startPoint = touch?.location(in: imageView)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard var touch = touches.first else { return }

        if let predicted = event?.predictedTouches(for: touch)?.last {
            touch = predicted
        }

        updatePath(in: imageView, to: touch)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        updatePath(in: imageView, to: touch)
        let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: imageView.bounds).image { _ in
            imageView.drawHierarchy(in: imageView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        shapeLayer.path = nil
        imageView.image = image
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    func updatePath(in view: UIView, to touch: UITouch) {
        let point = touch.location(in: view)
        guard view.bounds.contains(point) else { return }

        let bezier = UIBezierPath()

        bezier.move(to: startPoint!)
        bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: startPoint!.y))

        shapeLayer.path = bezier.cgPath
    }
}
```

This just renders the current line as a `CAShapeLayer`, but when the stroke is done, it creates a snapshot of the image view (permanently capturing the stroke in an image), removes the shape layer’s path, and updates the image view’s `image`.

But hopefully this answers the question on how to make the line horizontal.

Comment: can you update your code so I can draw in  @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView! I can draw anything in your code and I tried add the image view but its causing some errors which I don't know how to respond to.

Comment: Just add the shape layer to the image view. And, if you want, capture the image in `touchesEnded`. See revised answer.